# Android : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener - onScrollStateChanged (RecyclerView inside RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener, nestedrecyclerview

I am facing the issue with `RecyclerView` Scroll Listener.

On my screen, I have one `RecyclerView` with 3 items (*2 horizontally scrollable and 1 vertically scrollable*). Inside its adapter I am using another RecyclerView to display items in Horizontal LinearLayout and in Vertical GridLayout (Spam count 2). I am getting Scroll listener for parent RecyclerView, for Horizontal Linear Layout view which is inside Child Adapter, but not receiving scroll listener for Grid layout item.

- Parent RecyclerView (Receiving onScroll call)

  - Horizontal Scroll Items (Receiving onScroll call)
  - Horizontal Scroll Items (Receiving onScroll call)
  - Grid Layout Items (**Not receiving onScroll call**)

Please help me to get out of this.

Comment: Would help to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why u are using vertical `RecyclerView` inside another Vertical `RecyclerView` this will cause `RecyclerView` to lay down all the Items at once . its clearly against what `RecyclerView` stands for . you can use a move the Third one to parent `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @ADM It depends upon data we need to show on the screen. I am using horizontal and vertical recyclerview inside the parent one.